# Automate - data import from databricks to local using databricks CLI

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-community-edition

I have configured databricks-CLI and its working fine for the copy to local command.

`databricks fs cp dbfs:/FileStore/data/filename.csv C:\Users`

Can i automate this in python. Using "import databricks_cli".

Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Could you please add additional information about the issue or errors with an image?

Comment: There is no issue as such, just asking if there is a way to run this commands in python rather than in conda/Unix

Comment: Data importation from databricks to local device can be automated using Azure Blob storage using AzCopy command I can elaborate this method in detail further if required.